# Beamer - Footnotes at the very bottom

Tags: beamer, positioning, footnotes

I'm using beamer for a presentation, and introducing some references along it using `\footonote`. However, the spacing between the bottom of the slide and the last footnote reference is too big : I would like to save as much space as possible, for exemple by aligning the slide number and the footnote line.

How can I modify this in a clean way ? I would like to have the same result as using the footmisc package, which can not be used in beamer.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This causes probably more problems then it solves (for example overlapping if the footnotes are longer then one line), but in case you can sacrifice the navigation symbols:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{\usebeamercolor[fg]{title in head/foot}\usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    abc\footnote{text}
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]